# Why is $x \in \emptyset$ considered undetermined by WolframAlpha?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, wolfram-alpha

In an exercise, I had to prove, that the following statement is true:

$A\setminus B = A \cap \bar{B}$

The task itself was not hard to solve, but I immediately had the question, if this statement would still hold for the empty set $\emptyset$

One can rewrite:

$A\setminus B = \{x|x\in A \wedge x\notin B\}$

My reasoning was, that if x is in the empty set and not in B, but the empty set is contained in every set, x must also be contained in B. But my reasoning also tells me that, if A is empty, $x\in A$ should be false.

However, when I try to input $x\in A$ into Wolfram Alpha, I get the result:

> undetermined (can be true or false)

I asked my professor and we both concluded that this was a mistake on WolframAlphas side, specifically because the Axiom of empty set has to hold

> A set $M$ is the empty, when the proposition $x \in M$ holds false for each x.

Out of curiosity though, I want to know where the problem is. Is my input wrong or do I have to use another expression in WolframAlpha?

We think that WolframAlpha is interpreting the empty set as an character (or constant). However, even with the input $x \in \{\}$ I get the same result.

Please note that this is my first term in university, so I might not understand every answer well.

Edit: Again, what I typed into WolframAlpha was "x element of empty set" and "x element of {}" respectively.

Comment: Where? In WolframAlpha I tried "x element of empty set" and "x element of {}".

Comment: Forget WolframAlpha for a moment and have another look at your reasoning: "$x$ is a member of $A$" (written $x \in A$) and "$x$ is contained in $A$" (written $x \subseteq A$) do not mean the same thing. $\emptyset \subseteq A$ holds for any $A$, but $\emptyset \in A$ only holds for some $A$.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE!! WolframAlhpa is still in process of development. For example, see the [A Problem WolframAlpha Can't Solve, But You Can $(615 + x^2 = 2^y$)'s video](https://youtu.be/DOISjFviqkM). Also, what was your input there?

Comment: Which emoty set?  A or B kr both?

Comment: The simple  statement 'x in A' is of course indeterminable.

Comment: So you are not asking a set theory question, or a logic question. You're asking for a WA support question.

Comment: Altough I assume that the answer of this particular case (x element of empty set to be false or true) has implications on the result of this exercise.

Comment: In my earlier comment, I should also have said "$x$ is in $A$" is standard terminology for "$x$ is an element of $A$". As regards WolframAlpha, don't treat any computer algebra system as a decision procedure for mathematical truth. In this case, it behaves as you describe, but presumably only because (1) it doesn't recognise that the truth value of $x \in \emptyset$ doesn't depend on the value of $x$ and (2) in cases it can't decide, it says the truth value "could be true or false" when it should say "I don't know how to determine that truth value or whether it can be determined".